# EXCEL - Nested ISBLANK statement

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with a nested isblank formula.

Looking at the image in the link below,

if B9 is blank, F10 should say "input Lw_Lw"

if C9 is blank, F10 should say "input Lw_Up"

if B9 and C9 are both blank, F10 will be blank

if B9 and C9 have data, F10 will calculate sum(b9-c9)

[image: snip of Excel table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little simpler

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B9), IF(ISBLANK(C9),"","input Lw_Lw"), IF(ISBLANK(C9),"input Lw_Up",SUM(B9:C9)))
Explanation
When B9 is blank ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
When B9 is not blank                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Just a note, not a criticism.  `ISBLANK()` will return FALSE if the box is filled in with a formula that returns an empty string `""`.  This is just a warning for the OP and future readers.  If the reference cells B9 and C9 have formula replace the `ISBLANK(B9)` with `B9=""`.

Comment: @ScottCraner I absolutly agree.  Perhaps better commented on the Q, as OP specifically asks about `IsBlank`

Comment: Thank you both Scott and Chris! I went with Chris's answer as it was a bit simpler. Formula worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

you can put this formula on cell F10:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B9), ISBLANK(C9)), "", IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B9)), NOT(ISBLANK(C9))), SUM(B9:C9), IF(ISBLANK(B9), "input Lw_Lw", "input Lw_Up")))
```

Comment: Just a note, not a criticism.  `ISBLANK()` will return FALSE if the box is filled in with a formula that returns an empty string `""`.  This is just a warning for the OP and future readers.  If the reference cells B9 and C9 have formula replace the `ISBLANK(B9)` with `B9=""`.

Comment: I know, but the question says to use ISBLANK: "I need help with a nested isblank formula."

Comment: I agree which is  why I upvoted.  But many times the Askers do not know the limitations of ISBLANK().  It was not a criticism but a note.